# What's the difference between a concept artist and a concept designer?

Tags: production

What's the difference between a concept artist and a concept designer? Do concept designer have to also be artists, or can they just design something and give a written form of what they had in mind to help concept artists draw the things they envisioned? I am asking, because some websites imply that concept designers have to also be artists, but I don't see how that's necessary.

https://gundam.fandom.com/wiki/Mobile_Suit_Gundam_-_the_Witch_from_Mercury

Here's an example, you have several mechanical designers and one concept artist, so I was wondering how exactly the job title was different when you see it in movies and whatnot.

Comment: For a concept designer to be effective in their job - in order to be able to effectively communicate their vision to the people who have to implement them, I could imagine them being an artist as being a pre-requisite.  I'm not answering because I have no involvement in the industry, so this is only a guess.